# on click , code executed more than once

Tags: jquery, html, click

for the purpose to give the user the possibility to write in arabic i write the following code
 html :

```
<div id="clavier" style="display: none;" title="Clavier arabe">
   <table>
   <tr><td>
  <button value="ر" class="charachter">ر</button>
  <button value="ز" class="charachter">ز</button>
  <button value="ذ" class="charachter">ذ</button>
 <button value="د" class="charachter">د</button>
   <button value="خ" class="charachter">خ</button>
   <button value="ح" class="charachter">ح</button>
   <button value="ج" class="charachter">ج</button>
  <button value="ث" class="charachter">ث</button>
  <button value="ت" class="charachter">ت</button>
  <button value="ب" class="charachter">ب</button>
  <button value="ا" class="charachter">ا</button>
    <button value="mm" class="delete" style="width: 80px;">sup</button> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
     <button value="ل" class="charachter" style="margin-left: 20px;">ل</button>
   <button value="ك" class="charachter">ك</button>
  <button value="ق" class="charachter" >ق</button>
 <button value="ف" class="charachter">ف</button>
   <button value="غ" class="charachter" >غ</button>
       <button value="ع" class="charachter">ع</button>
          <button value="ظ" class="charachter">ظ</button>
            <button value="ط" class="charachter">ط</button>
          <button value="ض" class="charachter">ض</button>
            <button value="ص" class="charachter">ص</button>
            <button value="ش" class="charachter">ش</button>
            <button value="س" class="charachter">س</button> 

             </td></tr>








  <tr><td>

    <button value="ى" class="charachter" style="margin-left: 40px;">ى</button>
   <button value="ئ" class="charachter">ئ</button>
   <button value="ؤ" class="charachter">ؤ</button>
   <button value="ء" class="charachter"  >ء</button>
   <button value="ة" class="charachter">ة</button>
   <button value="ي" class="charachter">ي</button>
   <button value="و" class="charachter">و</button>
   <button value="ه" class="charachter">ه</button>
   <button value="ن" class="charachter">ن</button>
   <button value="م" class="charachter">م</button>
   <button value="" class="clear">clear</button>

  </td></tr>



   <tr><td>
   <button value="" class="espace" style="height: 25px;width: 220px;margin-left: 60px;">espace</button>
   <button value="إ" class="charachter" >إ</button>
   <button value="أ" class="charachter">أ</button>
   <button value="آ" class="charachter">آ</button>
   <button value="ٱ" class="charachter">ٱ</button>

   </td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

jquery :

```
$(".arab").live("click", function() {
    arabInput = $(this);
    $("#clavier").dialog({
        width: '43%'
    });
    $(".charachter").live("click", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
        var string = arabInput.val();
        alert(string + $(this).val());
        arabInput.val(string + $(this).val());
    });
    $(".delete").live("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val(string.slice(0, -1));
    });
    $(".espace").live("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val(string + " ");
    });
    $(".clear").live("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val("");
    });
});​
```

the problem is that work fine for the first input , but onclick to second input i have the code executed twice and the same character is written twice 
for the third input it's tree times 
any idea , why i behaves like this ?

Comment: Try adding `return false` at the bottom of each click event to stop them from bubbling up.

Comment: Not sure why you're using `.live`. Aside from the fact that's it's deprecated in favor of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), are you generating that HTML dynamically?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl i tried this not working

Comment: @Blazemonger no this code is not generated dynamiccaly

Comment: @Blazemonger: depend on the version of jQuery OP is using. on() was added in 1.7 so if OP uses a lesser version then live() was replaced by delegate in 1.4.2

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, or use http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ to stop event bubbling.

Comment: jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HBYhg/1/ works fine.

Comment: You don't need live plus it's deprecated because of event bubbling. Might try $('.delete').each( then bind the click event.

Comment: @CaffGeek: Not the case when using `live()` one of the drawbacks of `live()` is `Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document.` See documentation for all the drawbacks `http://api.jquery.com/live/`. that is why one should use `on()`, `bind()` or `delegate()`, or any of the shortcuts as they apply, depending if you need to bind to static or dynamic elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as J Torres said, this code works fine the first time. But if you click on the input again, it adds new events to the buttons.

You can simple move the events outside of the $(".arab").click() method like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBYhg/2/) or remove the listeners on click [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBYhg/7/).

```
$(".arab").click(function(){
  arabInput = $(this);
  $("#clavier").show();

});

$(".charachter").click(function()
  { alert($(this).val());
  var string = arabInput.val();
  alert(string+$(this).val());
  arabInput.val(string+$(this).val());
});

$(".delete").click(function()
  { var string = arabInput.val();
  arabInput.val(string.slice(0, -1));
});

$(".espace").click(function()
  { var string = arabInput.val();
  arabInput.val(string+" ");
});

$(".clear").click(function()
  { var string = arabInput.val();
  arabInput.val("");
});
```

or

```
$(".arab").live("click", function() {
    arabInput = $(this);
    $("#clavier").show();
    $(".charachter").unbind('click').on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
        var string = arabInput.val();
        alert(string + $(this).val());
        arabInput.val(string + $(this).val());
    });
    $(".delete").unbind('click').on("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val(string.slice(0, -1));
    });
    $(".espace").unbind('click').on("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val(string + " ");
    });
    $(".clear").unbind('click').on("click", function() {
        var string = arabInput.val();
        arabInput.val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: add an other input with the same class attribute, you'll have get the problem i'm facing

Comment: @fatiDev Nope, works fine with the new method (putting the click event outside) : http://jsfiddle.net/HBYhg/3/

Comment: for the first live i can't change because it's for element that are generated dynamically , i changed the others , the problem is still here

Comment: @fatiDev Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HBYhg/7/. change .live( to .unbind('click').on(

Comment: that's working now with this unbind functions , but i want to understand more , what was the problem and how this function helps

Comment: The problem was that everytime you clicked on the input field, you would attach events to the buttons. So they would add up. After clicking 10 inputs fields, the buttons would execute 10 times because they had 10 listeners. Now, with "unbind" everytime you click on an input, unbind removes the click listener and right after adds a new one. So you only have 1 click listener executing the code.

Comment: @ComputerArts: As a side-note: if you are using `on()` use `off()` as it is the intended counterpart. Though `unbind` works off course.

Comment: nice! didn't know about 'off'

Answer (score 4):

It's occurring the number of times you're clicking it because you are re-registering the event handler each time you click.  You need to unbind the event handlers before adding new ones.